# What is the optimal level of 'communication' with an online purchase?

Tags: communication

Online shops seem to be slipping into 'overcommunicating' about online purchases.

Beyond an email/text to confirm details of a purchase, is there any need to send numerous emails/texts reporting where your package currently is ?

(and if so when does 'sufficient' become 'too many' ?)

Comment: You can add track option to locate where the package currently is if the locations are too many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those **extra** emails will be disregarded just like those too many promotional emails that shops keep sending!

Why do I need more than one email that:

**1-** Confirms my order with the order details.

**2-** Provides a link to track my order and to set up delivery notification (including where and when my package will be delivered).

I would expect another email in case:

**1-** Issue with my order (any issue with the order, or shipping delays, item no longer available...etc)

**2-** Tracking details were not available at the time of placing the order, so they need to send another email with tracking details.

There are some online shops that send **one** email only and yes it **works!**

Comment: A link in the (1) confirm email seems like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The number depends on how much info is available and when.

As a customer there are a few things I specifically care about.

1. Confirmation my order was placed successfully
2. When my order has been picked up for delivery (if say a retailer that ships via UPS)
3. When my order has shipped (and what is my tracking number)
4. Any delay/issue along the way (item is on backorder, etc.)
5. From the delivery company, any waypoint on route (sorting facility in Maine, transfer in Memphis, transfer in Denver, transfer in Portland, at border customs in Blaine, transfer in Calgary, sorting facility in Toronto, out for delivery, delivered)

For 1-3 if I can get all those details in 1 email... great. If not I want an email whenever the next level of info is available. For 4, it would be as needed. For the tracking, once I have the number I can track via the shipper (Eg UPS/DHL/FedEx)

Answer (score 0):

**Must:**

1. An order confirmation email with tracking and delivery details
2. Order delivered email along with invoice/delivery note depending on the country and legal requirements

**Optional:**

1. Cancel/return the order
2. Installation note/usage instructions
3. Feedback/review product
4. Repeat order/subscription reminder if the product is like medicines/FMCG/fashion consumable/magazine so on

**Reduce the number of emails and content of emails to a bare minimum to keep the focus on content**

Promotions must be on users' preference. Don't make a long list of preferences either. Keep them to maximum 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user!

When they check out, you can display a modal with the following (example) question:

[image: example modal sketch]

You can make some notifications mandatory, such as payment updates or whatever, but leave the rest up to the user.